# Execution failed for task ':games_services:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I am using [games_services](https://github.com/Abedalkareem/games_services) package for my flutter app but I'm not able to run my app in android emulator, it returns following error:

```bash
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':games_services:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (1.8) and 'compileDebugKotlin' (17).
```

Here is my files settings:

`android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.23'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9'
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`android/app/build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

//....

compileOptions {
  sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
  jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
//...
```

`settings.gradle`

```
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }

    plugins {
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version '8.3.1' apply false
}

include ":app"
```

`gradle.properties`

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4G
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

`gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-bin.zip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've solved the issue by**

1. Removing android folder and re-create it. I don't know why that works but it did!
2. Also you need to add

```
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.23" apply false
```

In `settings.gradle` remember `1.9.23` is my version you change it to version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

update kotlin to 1.8.10
and gradle to (android>gradle>wraper>gradlewraper.properties)
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip

hope it helps

Comment: downgrade form 8.4 to 7.6?!

Comment: yes , i had same kind error, updating to latest didn't change anything for me ,but after downgrading to the specified issue got fixed  :).